# gradle keeps failing in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

here are the errors I get. How do I download gradle `2.2.0`?

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.jar
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.pom
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0/gradle-2.2.0.jar
Required by:
    :Floating Stickies:unspecified
```

I even reinstalled it completely.

Comment: You will need to show your build.gradle files. Also, you can run Gradle (from the Terminal in Android Studio)  with options like `--info` or `--debug` to get more information. You should also be sure you have actually updated the Android Studio SDKs using the built-in updater.

Answer (score 2):

Change the gradle version in `build.gradle` file to 2.3.3 This is latest stable version in Android studio and change the `gradle-wrapper.properties` to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```